# DIV-Grid that can grow and shrink?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So below I have my page. It generates 4 div boxes (2x2) and gives them IDs dynamically. I want to be able to add rows/columns equal to the length/height. So if I add a column it will at 2 more div boxes and automatically place the "newline" class on the proper div to format things. But I also need it to work in reverse also, so if rows/columns get removed, it keeps everything organized.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#btn').click(function(){
                GenerateIDs();
            });

            // Generates IDs dynamically
            function GenerateIDs(){
                var row = 1;
                var col = 0;
                $('body div div').each(function(){
                    if ($(this).hasClass('newline'))
                        {
                        row += 1;
                        col = 1;
                        }
                    else
                        col += 1;
                    $(this).attr('id', row + '-' + col);
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        body div div {background:gray; border:1px solid black; float:left; height:50px; margin:5px; width:50px;}
        .newline {clear:left;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>

        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="newline"></div> <!-- Ideally dynamic from the start -->
        <div></div>

    </div>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="JQuery" />
</body>
</html>
```

So if I added the column...

```
    <div>

        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="newline"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>

    </div>
```

And then happen to add a row...

```
    <div>

        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="newline"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="newline"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: It would be easier to change the width of the container to set the number of divs in a row, than it would be to maintain the `newline` class upon insert and delete of divs.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's so obvious! Thanks!